# Update view params in Java class / play2

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play Framework 2.0. I am playing around with the helloworld sample.
I experienced the following problem:

View: (test.scala.html)

```
@(name: String,lastname:String)
...
```

Controller: (Test.java)

```
...
public static Result index() {
   return ok(test.render("First", "Last"));
}
```

Works so far. *BUT* if I change the view to:

```
@(name: String)  @* removed second param *@
```

and the controller to:

```
...
public static Result index() {
   return ok(test.render("First"));
}
```

Eclipse show an error in Test.java (controller)
The funny thing is that play compiles everything just fine. The rendering works - only eclipse is acting up.

The only way to solve this problem is to modify the view slightly, delete the generated class-files in target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed/views/html/test.*
Now play compiles and generates the test*.class files and everything works.

But I am sure there is a better way...

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class for the view is not modified until you load it in the web browser. Until then, Eclipse has no way of knowing the controller is now valid.

Comment: Or he can run the `~compile` or `~run` sbt target, so the template will be recompiled each time its changes are saved.